# Insert data in Excel sheet using C#

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, excel-2010

I'm trying to insert data inside Excel sheet using C# everything in code and run is OK but the data did not insert in the Excel sheet.

Hint: I inserted another data in another Excel sheet using the same code an data inserted successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
    var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"Excel.xlsx");
    Excel._Worksheet excelWorkSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];
    excelWorkSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
    Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
    excelApp.Visible = true;
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "Insert";
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "your";
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, "C"] = "text";
    excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, "D"] = "here";
    excelWorkbook.Close(true, "output.xlsx");
    excelApp.Quit();
```